# Is it possible to call a MySQL stored procedure from Ruby?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, stored-procedures

When I try to call a stored procedure from Rails, I get this exception:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: PROCEDURE pipeline-ws_development.match_save_all can't return a result set in the given context: call match_save_all()
    from /Users/otto/Projects/Futures/src/pipeline-ws/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:150:in `log'
    from /Users/otto/Projects/Futures/src/pipeline-ws/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:281:in `execute'
    from (irb):3
```

There is a page in the [Rails Wiki that discusses a patch](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/StoredProceduresInMySql) for the MySQL adapter that resolves this issue, but it's out-of-date and doesn't seem to work anymore.

The configuration code enables stored procedures correctly, but it still has the issue with the connection getting out of sync after a stored procedure call and the new `call_sp` method doesn't work anymore.

Any suggestions for how to get this working?

This is the code I'm using:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection("call storedproc()")
```

It throws the same exception whether `storedproc()` returns any results or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it work to wrap the procedure in a function? If Ruby's barfing due to no rows returned (`...can't return a result set in the given context...`), this may fix it:

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE PROCEDURE tProc()
BEGIN
    SET @a = 'test';
END;
$

CREATE FUNCTION tFunc()
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    CALL tProc();
    RETURN 1;
END;
$

DELIMITER ;

SELECT tFunc() FROM DUAL;
>> 1

SELECT @a FROM DUAL;
>> 'test'
```

Although, realistically, this isn't a very extensible solution.

**Followup: I'm pretty n00by at Ruby/ActiveRecord, but this example definitely works**

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(authopts)

class TestClass < ActiveRecord::Base
end

test_class = TestClass.new
puts %{#{test_class.connection.select_one('SELECT tFunc() AS tf FROM DUAL')}}
>> tf1
```

Using `CALL tProc()` resulted in an error similar to yours.

Comment: Your example works, but with our stored proc I get "ERROR 1415 (0A000): Not allowed to return a result set from a function".  I'm going to talk to the guy who wrote them and see if we can't rewrite them to return things like your example.

Comment: This moves us forward, but we still have a couple procs that need to return a lot of data that won't work in variables.

Comment: I went ahead and accepted, as this seems to be the best current solution.  There's still the issue of returning lots of data, but it's been a few days and no one has come up with something better. I  don't think it exists without fixing the MySQL adapter.

Comment: I'm a little unclear -- can procs return data? I'm fairly sure procs in MySQL return nothing. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

I've submitted a patch to Rails 2.3.4 which gives a configuration option to fix this problem. Please stop by my ticket and show your support for it!

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3151-mysql-adapter-update-to-enable-use-of-stored-procedures

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute? This method should allow you to execute some arbitrary SQL statement that isn't naively supported in the Active Record wrapper.

Comment: That is what I'm using, and I get that exception.