# Can I use stored procedures with ruby on rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can I use stored procedures with ruby on rails ?

I am using mysql as database and ruby on rails.

please provide me any of the example for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Duplicate ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471517/is-it-possible-to-call-a-mysql-stored-procedure-from-ruby)
if not:

```
class MyRubyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.select_some_records
       connection.select_all "exec mysql_stored_proc 'argument1', 'argument2'"
    end
end
```

to enable use of stored procedures look at [this](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3151-mysql-adapter-update-to-enable-use-of-stored-procedures)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you do your business logic IN rails.

Writing your own queries to execute in rails is awkward, error prone, and not likely portable to other databases.