# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql::Error: PROCEDURE db_name.proc_spName can't return a result set in the given context: 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have use activerecord to access data from db. It works fine in localhost but when I tried it on another server, I get the following errors:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql::Error: PROCEDURE db_name.proc_spName can't return a result set in the given context: CALL proc_spName(............)):
    /vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:188:in `log'
    /vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:310:in `execute'
    /app/controllers/keywordprocessor_controller.rb:306:in `result'
    /vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1256:in `send'
```

BTW, below is the line where I get the following errors

```
sql = "CALL proc_getresults"
res = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: A similar question with a possibly useful answer was asked already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471517/is-it-possible-to-call-a-mysql-stored-procedure-from-ruby

Answer (score 2):

As BJG showed you that link pretty much explains it; as ActiveRecord is expecting a result set to be returned. You could use something along these lines for calling stored procedures using execute.

```
 SELECT proc_getresults() as Results FROM TABLE ...
```